xssprotection, noframe, nosniff not present on every request
I have a custom httpActionAdabter and i match matchers once also in the action adapter pac4jcsrf token and other matchers only will be present on register login and logout what i do to have them on all request?
i tried using security filter and make matches these matchers on all request but it doesn't affect it in security logic with logs i see them that are included in requests in webcontext and in browser inspect element i can't see response header unless on callback url.
Using pac4j v6 and playframework v3

A fix has been provided via the following PR: https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j/pull/671
